# Materialised View : Aggregate query involving partitionn operator

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Ran into a wall, trying to insert into Tableb with rows that meet a certain condition after insertion into Tablea

```
drop materialized view mv ;
drop materialized view log on tablea ;

create materialized view log on tablea
with rowid, sequence ( tino, price )
including new values;

create materialized view mv
refresh fast on commit
enable query rewrite
as
SELECT  tino,sum(price)
FROM tablea PARTITION(PART_201609)
group by tino;
```

The above will return the ORA-12054 : cannot set ON COMMIT Refresh attribute.
Is this a limitation ? Aggregate query not having a partition operator in it?
Table is too larger, i would want my view to only have data specific to a certain period/month
When i remove the `PARTITION(PART_201609)` and ran as below i was able to successfully create the view :

```
create materialized view mv
refresh fast on commit
enable query rewrite
as
SELECT  tino,sum(price)
FROM tablea
group by tino;
```

-- EDIT -- Include tablea's DDL

-- Create table

```
create table TABLEA
(
tino  NUMBER not null,
price VARCHAR2(200),
dated DATE
)
partition by range (DATED)
(
partition PART_201608 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
partition PART_201609 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
partition PART_201610 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')));
```

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the `tablea` table - specifically the partition key? It looks like the key isn't in the group-by, which is a requirement for [PCT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/advmv.htm#DWHSG00324). Have you checked the query's [capabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8218)?

Comment: Added the DDL in the edit

Comment: Not familiar with partitioned tables, but... can't you, instead of including the PARTITION specification in the MV definition, use a WHERE filter instead? `where dated between ... and ...`

Comment: Don't want to look at the entire table , just need to pick from a particular partition which holds monthly data

Comment: You don't need scan all table. Just write query with where and see plan, look  and PSTART, PSTOP it shows only 1 partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `dbms_mview.explain_mview` procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67191) to see why your proposed query can't be used for a fast-refresh-on-commit MV:

```
begin
  dbms_mview.explain_mview(q'[SELECT  tino,sum(price)
FROM tablea PARTITION(PART_201609)
group by tino]');
end;
/

select capability_name, possible, msgno, msgtxt from mv_capabilities_table;

CAPABILITY_NAME                P      MSGNO MSGTXT                                                                                   
------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PCT                            N                                                                                                      
REFRESH_COMPLETE               Y                                                                                                      
REFRESH_FAST                   N                                                                                                      
REWRITE                        Y                                                                                                      
PCT_TABLE                      N       2067 no partition key or PMARKER or join dependent expression in select list                   
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      N       2169 the materialized view contains partition extended table name                              
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2143 SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)                                                             
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2146 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled                                  
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     N       2161 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled                              
REFRESH_FAST_PCT               N       2157 PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the materialized view                  
REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH        Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH     Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_GENERAL                N       2169 the materialized view contains partition extended table name                              
REWRITE_PCT                    N       2158 general rewrite is not possible or PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables        
PCT_TABLE_REWRITE              N       2185 no partition key or PMARKER in select list
```

As far as I'm aware there isn't any way around the the 2169 error:

> 02169, 00000, "the materialized view contains partition extended table name"
>   // *Cause:  Fast refresh of materialized aggregate views and/or materialized
>   //          join views are not supported if they were defined using partition
>   //          extended table names.
>   // *Action: Create the fast refreshable materialized view without using
>   //          partition extended table names or create the materialized view as
>   //          a complete refresh materialized view.

Specifying the partition by name is somewhat unusual anyway; you can achieve the same thing by specifying the date range, and Oracle will limit the query to the relevant partition anyway. You get the same execution plan from:

```
explain plan for
select tino, sum(price)
from tablea partition(part_201609)
group by tino;
```

and

```
explain plan for
select tino, sum(price)
from tablea
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by tino;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| Id  | Operation               | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |        |     1 |   115 |    15   (7)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY          |        |     1 |   115 |    15   (7)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|        |     1 |   115 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLEA |     1 |   115 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You'll see a higher row count than I get from my dummy table, but note the PSTART and PSTOP columns.

Using that for your MV still isn't quite enough though:

```
begin
  dbms_mview.explain_mview(q'[select tino, sum(price)
from tablea
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by tino]');
end;
/

select capability_name, possible, msgno, msgtxt from mv_capabilities_table;

CAPABILITY_NAME                P      MSGNO MSGTXT                                                                                   
------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PCT                            N                                                                                                      
REFRESH_COMPLETE               Y                                                                                                      
REFRESH_FAST                   N                                                                                                      
REWRITE                        Y                                                                                                      
PCT_TABLE                      N       2067 no partition key or PMARKER or join dependent expression in select list                   
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      N       2081 mv log does not have all necessary columns                                                
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2143 SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)                                                             
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2146 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled                                  
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2142 COUNT(*) is not present in the select list                                                
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2143 SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)                                                             
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     N       2161 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled                              
REFRESH_FAST_PCT               N       2157 PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the materialized view                  
REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH        Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH     Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_GENERAL                Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_PCT                    N       2158 general rewrite is not possible or PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables        
PCT_TABLE_REWRITE              N       2185 no partition key or PMARKER in select list
```

You need to resolve the 2067 error:

> 02067, 00000, "no partition key or PMARKER or join dependent expression in select list"
>   // *Cause:    The capability in question is not supported when the materialized
>   //            view unless the select list (and group by list if a GROUP BY
>   //            clause is present) includes the partition key or
>   //            PMARKER function reference to the table in question or an expression
>   //            join dependent on the partitioning column of the table in question.
>   // *Action:   Add the partition key or a PMARKER function reference or a join dependent
>   //            expression to the select list (and the GROUP BY clause, if present).

... which is related to [partition change tracking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/advmv.htm#DWHSG00324). You can add [a partition marker](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/advmv.htm#sthref274) to the select list and group-by, which again gets the same execution plan (PSTART/PSTOP), but now allows fast-refresh:

```
explain plan for
select dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino, sum(price)
from tablea
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

begin
  dbms_mview.explain_mview(q'[select dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino, sum(price)
from tablea
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino]');
end;
/

CAPABILITY_NAME                P      MSGNO MSGTXT                                                                                   
------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PCT                            Y                                                                                                      
REFRESH_COMPLETE               Y                                                                                                      
REFRESH_FAST                   Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE                        Y                                                                                                      
PCT_TABLE                      Y                                                                                                      
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      N       2081 mv log does not have all necessary columns                                                
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2143 SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)                                                             
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2146 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled                                  
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2142 COUNT(*) is not present in the select list                                                
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  N       2143 SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)                                                             
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     N       2161 see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled                              
REFRESH_FAST_PCT               Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH        Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH     Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_GENERAL                Y                                                                                                      
REWRITE_PCT                    Y                                                                                                      
PCT_TABLE_REWRITE              Y
```

And you can indeed use that query to create your MV:

```
create materialized view mv
refresh fast on commit
enable query rewrite
as
select dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino, sum(price)
from tablea
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino;

Materialized view MV created.
```

---

If you want to enable all capabilities in the MV you can add the `dated` column to your MV log:

```
create materialized view log on tablea
with rowid, sequence ( dated, tino, price )
including new values;
```

and include the missing aggregates in your MV query:

```
select dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino, sum(price), count(price), count(*)
from tablea a
where dated >= date '2016-09-01'
and dated < date '2016-10-01'
group by dbms_mview.pmarker(rowid), tino
```

Not relevant, but also note that you can, if it's beneficial, partition the MV view log too:

```
create materialized view log on tablea
partition by range (dated)
(
  partition PART_201608 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
  partition PART_201609 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
  partition PART_201610 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
)
with rowid, sequence ( dated, tino, price )
including new values;
```